# NavLink onActive callback

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Is there a way to know when the `NavLink` is active? something like this?:

```
<NavLink to="/mylink" activeClassName="active" onActive={this.doSomething} />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `NavLink`'s `isActive` callback to achieve this. `isActive` lets you define your own behaviour when the link is active; it gets the `match` and your current `location` object. You can modify it to take a callback that will fire if match is true. Here is a simple example:

```
const isActive = onActive => (match, location) => {
  if (match) {
    onActive();
  }
  return match;
}

const App = () => {
  const onActive = () => console.log("link is active");
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <NavLink to="/abc" activeClassName="active" isActive={isActive(onActive)}>Go To ABC</NavLink>
        <Route path="/abc" render={() => <h1>ABC Page</h1>} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: isActive is [removed](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7991) from router v5